# How to prevent entering two of the same numbers in 2 or more inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I was wondering how I can stop a user from inputting the same number twice in this code.

I ask the user: "Input the first number", "Input the second number", and "Input the third number". I would like to prevent the user from saying, for example, 2, 2 and 5, or something. All 3 inputted numbers must be different.

```
def middle(num1, num2, num3) :
    return min(max(num1,num2),max(num2,num3),max(num1,num3))

num1 = input("Enter the first number: ")
num2 = input("Enter the second number: ")
num3 = input("Enter the third number: ")
print("The center number is: ")
print(middle(num1,num2,num3))
```

Answer (score 0):

I mean:

```
if num1 == num2 or num1 == num3 or num2 == num3:
```

Comment: It kind of worked. But it still displays the answer
Sláðu inn fyrstu tölu: 3                                                                                                                                     Sláðu inn seinni tölu: 3
Sláðu inn þriðju tölu: 4
Bannað að slá inn sömu tölu.
Miðju talan er:
3

Comment: Nevermiind i got it. I just had to put else for the print.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an endless loop that only breaks, if the number is different from the first numbers.

```py
num1 = input("Sláðu inn fyrstu tölu: ")
while True:
    num2 = input("Sláðu inn seinni tölu: ")
    if num2 == num1:
        print("This number has already been choosen")
        continue
    else:
        break
while True:
    num3 = input("Sláðu inn seinni tölu: ")
    if num3 == num1 or num3 == num2:
        print("This number has already been choosen")
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it.
Shoutout to Recoded for helping me so fast. So you need to put this "
if num1 == num2 or num1 == num3 or num2 == num3:
print("Bannað að slá inn sömu tölu.")
else:
print("Miðju talan er: ")
print(middle(num1,num2,num3))"
into the code :)

```
def middle(num1, num2, num3) :
    return min(max(num1,num2),max(num2,num3),max(num1,num3))
num1 = input("Sláðu inn fyrstu tölu: ")
num2 = input("Sláðu inn seinni tölu: ")
num3 = input("Sláðu inn þriðju tölu: ")
if num1 == num2 or num1 == num3 or num2 == num3:
    print("Bannað að slá inn sömu tölu.")
else:
    print("Miðju talan er: ")
    print(middle(num1,num2,num3))
```